# Fail to read Japanese Characters via System.in

Tags: java, character-encoding, system.in

Code:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter Name : ");
String name = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println(name);

String encoding = "UTF-8";
System.out.println(new String(name.getBytes(encoding), "euc-jp"));
System.out.println(new String(name.getBytes(encoding), "Shift_JIS"));
System.out.println(new String(name.getBytes(encoding), "ISO-2022-JP"));
System.out.println(new String(name.getBytes(encoding), "ISO8859-1"));
```

Input:

> Enter Name : たなかです

Output:

> �F�Q���N�@
>
> 鐃�鐃�鐃緒申鐃�鐃�
>
> �ｿｽF�ｿｽQ�ｿｽ�ｿｽ�ｿｽN�ｿｽ@
>
> ���F���Q���������N���@
>
> ï¿½Fï¿½Qï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Nï¿½@

None of them are readable Japanese.
I've also tried `InputStreamReader` and `DataInputStream` with `Byte[]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use chinese and japanese character as string in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067628/how-to-use-chinese-and-japanese-character-as-string-in-java)

Comment: `System.out.println(name)` should work fine - the other lines don't make much sense. The problem is probably that your console can't print those characters. See [demo](http://ideone.com/iDs0t7).

Comment: can you show us how are using "encoding" variable bdw?

Comment: encoding should be = "UTF-8", I have tried to compile with encoding and running in console. both doesn't work

Comment: Instead of reading in an input, does printing a hardcoded string of Japanese characters work? E.g. `System.out.println("頑張ります!");` @TanakaSakana

Comment: println works, it prints out as it is

Comment: I think it should be problem of inputstream , however , new scanner(System.in, "UTF-8") not works

Comment: Can you post what the output should look like so that we can compare?

Answer (score 0):

#### How to print the string properly to console with your code

`name.getBytes(encoding)` in your code will get the raw-byte representation of the `String name` with UTF-8 encoding. So when you type "たなかです" in console, you will get the array of byte `{0xE3, 0x81, 0x9F, 0xE3, 0x81, 0xAA, 0xE3, 0x81, 0x8B, 0xE3, 0x81, 0xA7, 0xE3, 0x81, 0x99}`.

It is UTF-8 based representation, so the only encoding you can specify in the 2nd argument of the constructor `String(byte[] bytes, String charsetName)` is `UTF-8`.

```java
System.out.println(new String(name.getBytes(encoding), "UTF-8"));
```

It converts the byte array `{0xE3, 0x81, 0x9F, ... }` to a `String` object, and prints to the console properly.

#### How to get the internal representation of a String as a byte array

`String` object uses UTF-16 for the internal text representation (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/overview.html for details).

So you have to use `name.getBytes("UTF-16")` when you want to get the byte array that same as the internal text representation. You can reverse it to a `String` object with `System.out.println(new String(name.getBytes("UTF-16"), "UTF-16"));`.

Answer (score -1):

there is slight problem in your following code snippet,  you are using same encoding for different charsets,

```
String encoding = System.getProperty("file.encoding"); 
System.out.println(new String(name.getBytes(encoding), "UTF-8"));
```

assuming you want to print the japanese characters using different charset's ,use this

```
 System.out.println(new String(name.getBytes("euc-jp"), "euc-jp"));
 System.out.println(new String(name.getBytes("Shift_JIS"), "Shift_JIS"));
 System.out.println(new String(name.getBytes("ISO-2022-JP"), "ISO-2022-JP"));
 System.out.println(new String(name.getBytes("ISO8859-1"), "ISO8859-1"));
```