# Japanese text displays squares in image

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, fonts, awt

I am  trying  to  create  an  image and  put japanese text  on  it  . It works  fine   in  local.  but  when I upload  and  deploy  my  project      in  amazone web service  ec2  , the  japanese  text  displays  squares  in the image  . (I am   using  wildfly 9 as server  )

Image created :

[image]

my code is below :

```
void CreateImage(String topic, String name, String id, boolean candidate,int idvideo) {
    try {



        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO
                .read(new File(ImagePath));

        Graphics graphics = bufferedImage.getGraphics();
        String  myString="承認待ち he new guy ट्रेल्स   " ;
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        byte ptext[] = myString.getBytes("UTF-8");
        String value;
        value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
        graphics.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 10));

        graphics.drawString(value, 10, 90);
            if (id != null && !id.equals("")) {
            graphics.drawString("大学で学んだこと", 0, 100);
        }

        if (candidate) {
            ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png",
                    new File( path1));
        } else {
            ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png",
                    new File(path2));

        }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you saved .java file with Unicode ?

Comment: or it is ansi ?

Comment: Pretty sure `graphics.setFont(Font.getFont(""));` is a guaranteed failure on "not your computer". Why would Amazon have a default font for Japanese set up? Or almost any other language that doesn't match its server region, really.

Comment: Seems like your server doesn't have fonts with Japanese characters. Try to find and install appropriate font as described [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/234520/does-ubuntu-provide-extra-fonts-through-a-font-package).

Comment: if you are using javac use this command : `javac -encoding UTF-8`

Comment: I think this question has a duplicate one : [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067628/how-to-use-chinese-and-japanese-character-as-string-in-java)

Comment: I used also  new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 10)   ; and i get  the same  problem .Is Asian font support is available in the Amazon  or  i should  install it   ????

Comment: 1) Better to post a [mcve]. 2) `new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 10)` This is very fragile in that it presumes Arial font is installed. 3) Use [`Font.canDisplayUpTo(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#canDisplayUpTo-java.lang.String-) to discover which fonts can display a given string.

Answer (score 0):

I  solved  it   by  installing  Japanese  support in  the  AWS  server .
As well as not supporting any Asian characters out the box, it doesn't have them in any of its Amazon repositories.I did manage to register the centos repository for yum on the box, so we could install packs from that.

sudo yum groupinstall "Korean Support" "Chinese Support" "Japanese Support"