# How to support chinese character in FOP

Tags: java, apache

I want to print Chinese character in my pdf but it is showing like ########.
Any suggestions would be welcomed. please help.

Comment: please provide your question with code sample to better understanding

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use chinese and japanese character as string in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067628/how-to-use-chinese-and-japanese-character-as-string-in-java)

Comment: try change FOP config and add SimSun.ttf                              FopFactory fopFactory;
fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();
File configFile = new File("path/to/config.xml");
fopFactory.setUserConfig(configFile);